# Select Numbers which start with a number and zeros after

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select, numbers

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Y74T.png)I am trying to select only rounded numbers like 1,1000,100000,200000,4000 from a large data set
I want to select all rows with amount starting with whole numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and zeros after or just the whole number itself without zeros after.

```
SELECT [INPUTTER]
      ,[OUR_REFERENCE]
      ,[TRANS_REFERENCE]
      ,[COMMON_REF]
      ,[RECID]
      ,[ACCOUNT_NUMBER]
      ,[TRANSACTION_CODE]
      ,[NARRATIVE]
      ,[AMOUNT_LCY]
      ,[AMOUNT_FCY]
      ,[VALUE_DATE]
      ,[BOOKING_DATE]
      ,[CURRENCY]
      ,[EXCHANGE_RATE]
      ,[PRODUCT_CATEGORY]
      ,[PL_CATEGORY]
      ,[REVERSAL_MARKER]
  FROM [Steward].[dbo].[vwSTMT_01]

  v
  where AMOUNT_LCY LIKE '[1-9]%' and AMOUNT_LCY NOT LIKE '[1-9]%[^0]';
```

[Sample data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsIlL.png)

| COMMON_REF | ACCOUNT_NUMBER | AMOUNT_LCY | BOOKING_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FT2300341CMW | 1007317488 | (400.00) | 20230103 |
| FT23003TFL28 | 1037960264 | 1,500.00 | 20230103 |
| FT23003WBY7K | 1042704004 | (8,500.00) | 20230103 |
| FT23003D2J6Z | 1004217628 | 3,358.97 | 20230103 |
| FT23003VJR6D | 1037944625 | (0.05) | 20230103 |
| FT23003QNV7H | 1001527777 | (0.05) | 20230103 |
| FT23003YP6WJ | 1049397007 | (81.00) | 20230103 |
| FT23003VHKJ8 | 1036092498 | (151,075.49) | 20230103 |
| FT23003GYQB5 | 1048216998 | (6,000,000.00) | 20230103 |
| FT23003FNL7V | 1037054239 | 150.00 | 20230103 |
| FT23003Z8QTR | 1046957063 | (96,000.00) | 20230103 |
| FT230030ZVM8 | 1001132217 | 400,000.00 | 20230103 |
| FT230036X791 | 1044191616 | (382.50) | 20230103 |
| FT230037HSQD | 1050760778 | 6,210.00 | 20230103 |
| FT23003M3Y1G | 1041195688 | (0.05) | 20230103 |
| FT23003CGLT5 | 1005963741 | (15.00) | 20230103 |
| FT230030F64D | 1007549907 | 1,300.00 | 20230103 |
| FT23003D0RJH | 1037052627 | (600.00) | 20230103 |
| FT23003LLB2P | 1006395291 | (100.00) | 20230103 |
| FT23003KN1MQ | 1007802451 | (100.00) | 20230103 |
| FT23003GLSLV | 1004217728 | (15.48) | 20230103 |
| FT230031H1SD | 1041867187 | (21,516.85) | 20230103 |
| FT23003Q7XY1 | 1046000408 | (130.93) | 20230103 |
| FT2300346BG1 | 1000235837 | (20,212.00) | 20230103 |
| FT2300305W3Q | 1002551477 | (263.24) | 20230103 |
| FT23003N7NTK | 1044159631 | (63.00) | 20230103 |
| FT23003T0BMB | 1008695411 | (60.00) | 20230103 |
| FT230034FY9R | 1004217744 | 5,174.61 | 20230103 |
| FT23003RZ3RD | 1048078938 | (5,760.10) | 20230103 |
| FT23003P9TV2 | 1001436143 | (80.00) | 20230103 |
| FT230030G8RV | 1050753917 | (600.00) | 20230103 |
| FT23003W3020 | 1037799517 | (600.00) | 20230103 |
| FT23003R5KV1 | 1008746075 | (250.00) | 20230103 |
| FT230030Z54W | 1037339691 | (250.00) | 20230103 |
| FT23003R9VRS | 1007468381 | (0.05) | 20230103 |
| FT2300313TVV | 1042939885 | (200.00) | 20230103 |
| FT23003Y4MT2 | 1044950347 | (200.00) | 20230103 |
| FT2300361Z22 | 1002790471 | (100.00) | 20230103 |
| FT230035M35B | 1007117031 | (250.00) | 20230103 |
| FT23003FY5NL | 1008734848 | (23.20) | 20230103 |
| FT23003B7M2T | 1037793384 | (232.79) | 20230103 |
| FT23003SQC51 | 1041276874 | (4,000.00) | 20230103 |
| FT23003G94KF | 1008832947 | (20.00) | 20230103 |
| FT230035B3ZC | 1047280598 | (12,750.00) | 20230103 |
| FT23003KNR29 | 1008758267 | (5,000.00) | 20230103 |
| FT23003TN4BX | 1044872378 | (700.00) | 20230103 |
| FT2300380JHZ | 1008596308 | (600.00) | 20230103 |
| FT23003C9XB1 | 1008604707 | (259.14) | 20230103 |
| FT230030KL7S | 1011544254 | (1,000.00) | 20230103 |
| FT2300317HHY | 1040010447 | (166,601.51) | 20230103 |
| FT23003G95QD | 1043004917 | (51.00) | 20230103 |
| FT23003D1CHF | 1000094664 | (0.05) | 20230103 |
| FT23003XJMVP | 1036870498 | 2,469.96 | 20230103 |
| FT23003CQJN7 | 1041527877 | (0.05) | 20230103 |
| FT23003M849Z | 1037758333 | (226.80) | 20230103 |
| AAACT23003NQLMJLFT | 1040303417 | 172,204.07 | 20230103 |
| FT23003WPDYL | 1044191616 | (198.00) | 20230103 |
| FT23003K0J6B | 1048803098 | (100.00) | 20230103 |
| FT230036QHSV | 1036365109 | (2,552.04) | 20230103 |
| FT230037KDVQ | 1001647683 | 300,000.00 | 20230103 |
| FT23003QXTHR | 1036365109 | (205.00) | 20230103 |
| FT23003K5194 | 1047636643 | (250.00) | 20230103 |
| FT2300324W9X | 1000235837 | (4,000.00) | 20230103 |
| FT23003F0P75 | 1001501662 | (46.14) | 20230103 |
| FT23003HMNY9 | 1008556578 | (8,840.00) | 20230103 |
| FT2300351D2R | 1037794167 | 1,809.00 | 20230103 |
| FT23003Z477H | 1001398047 | (0.05) | 20230103 |
| FT230033W0PT | 1008753349 | 1,300.00 | 20230103 |
| FT230039Q07V | 1007509673 | (125.00) | 20230103 |
| FT23003FXVKF | 1007985742 | (14,250.00) | 20230103 |
| FT23003W4VLP | 1040386878 | (991.76) | 20230103 |
| FT2300395Y46 | 1003696355 | (250.00) | 20230103 |
| FT230030WQ36 | 1037930667 | (2,000.00) | 20230103 |
| FT23003N4F63 | 1037913797 | (20.00) | 20230103 |
| FT23003BVGX4 | 1044286315 | (80.00) | 20230103 |
| 1008340297-202301-SW | 1008340297 | (19,600.00) | 20230103 |
| FT230031826D | 1006859689 | 7,020.00 | 20230103 |
| FT23003T9KW8 | 1048465273 | (2,439.96) | 20230103 |
| FT23003CFQX6 | 1008495967 | (10,000.00) | 20230103 |
| FT23003H00NS | 1008489738 | (1,600.00) | 20230103 |
| FT23003ZHPNB | 1049602118 | (0.05) | 20230103 |
| FT23003V3FC7 | 1007640621 | (500.00) | 20230103 |
| FT2300305W3Q | 1002551477 | (13,161.89) | 20230103 |
| FT23003SBS7Q | 1007904335 | 1,000.00 | 20230103 |
| FT230036L6BC | 1007844518 | (100.00) | 20230103 |
| FT2300350S0S | 1042105879 | (2,460.00) | 20230103 |
| FT230030C5BX | 1006859767 | 2,800.00 | 20230103 |
| FT23003JK1TL | 1004484785 | (250.00) | 20230103 |
| FT23003THV89 | 1047106113 | (2,279.99) | 20230103 |
| FT23003WGJKQ | 1036963103 | 2,000.00 | 20230103 |
| FT23003B9F8G | 1007813887 | (18.00) | 20230103 |
| FT23003TXWXH | 1035363811 | 1,955.00 | 20230103 |
| FT23003GNPPN | 1000019638 | (13.50) | 20230103 |
| FT23003YZ52T | 1007250416 | 3,605.98 | 20230103 |
| FT23003MV4CJ | 1034346433 | (211,206.68) | 20230103 |
| TT230035VSY9 | 1037936711 | 2,014.34 | 20230103 |
| FT23003VHKGL | 1042783494 | (220.00) | 20230103 |
| FT23003KWMTR | 1043817295 | 245,000.00 | 20230103 |
| FT23003R9QQT | 1003419629 | (600.00) | 20230103 |
| FT23003PLJ0S | 1004217884 | (53.58) | 20230103 |
| FT23003FR0GT | 1007025827 | (1,000.00) | 20230103 |
| FT23003TLQ7Y | 1044500392 | (100.00) | 20230103 |
| FT23003BZNHM | 1042939885 | (150.00) | 20230103 |
| FT23003RZ8TJ | 1037162252 | (123.50) | 20230103 |
| FT23003TG55M | 1008772459 | (100.00) | 20230103 |
| FT23003TMVH7 | 1048396767 | (250.00) | 20230103 |
| FT23003GWZ7F | 1007482031 | (72.32) | 20230103 |
| FT23003Z9BJS | 1040237409 | (40,000.00) | 20230103 |
| FT230033V3WV | 1035388385 | 7,000.00 | 20230103 |
| FT23003KG9SD | 1005580168 | 15,000.00 | 20230103 |

Comment: You can get fancier with your [pattern matching](https://study.com/academy/lesson/regular-expressions-in-sql-server-databases-implementation-use.html#transcriptMain) in SQL Server.

Comment: is `AMOUNT_LCY` a character field or a numeric field?

Comment: In your edit to the question you missed the edit in the answer. Does `[1-9]%[^0]%` not `[1-9]%[^0]` do what you need? If not give a specific value that is not behaving the way you expect. No need for tons of data that needs to be downloaded from a third party site

Comment: @Sean I is a numeric field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you could use a couple of `LIKE` expressions here. First you can use `LIKE '[1-9]%'` to get only get rows that start with a numerical character (I assume they can't start with a `0` but you can add that), and then `NOT LIKE '[1-9]%[^0]'` to exclude any rows that have a character that *isn't* a `0` after the first digit:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES('1'),
            ('20'),
            ('31'),
            ('400'),
            ('56238'),
            ('600000'),
            ('a00'))V(ID)
WHERE V.ID LIKE '[1-9]%'
   AND V.ID NOT LIKE '[1-9]%[^0]%';
```

Answer (score 1):

You could parse it to a decimal and check if it has a fractional part using modulo.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
    TRY_CAST(TRIM('()' FROM t.YourColumn) AS decimal(18,9))
)) v(Trimmed)
WHERE v.Trimmed % 1.0 > 0
  AND CAST(v.Trimmed / POWER(10E0, FLOOR(LOG10(v.Trimmed))) AS decimal(18, 9)) % 1.0;
```